# setting django project for production / development enviroment

Tags: django, continuous-integration, scalable

I am writing a Django project that it needs to be divided as production/development, but however my project looks like this, how can I organize in order to execute `python manage.py runserver` for dev or prod.

```
.
├── apps
│   ├── account
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   └── __pycache__
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── course
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── quizgame
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   └── __pycache__
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   └── site
│       └── __pycache__
└── app
    └── __pycache__

16 directories
```

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, `settings.py` must be inside `app` directory. So, you need to create new directory inside `app`, for example with name `settings`. Then you need to modify `manage.py` and set the next code:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '<root_folder_name>.app.settings')
```

Then, you can create two new files `dev_settings.py` and `prod_settings.py` in `settings` folder.

Now, you can run code with other settings, but you need to add parameter `--settings=settings.dev_settings` to all your management commands, for example:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=settings.dev_settings
```

or

```
python manage.py migrate --settings=settings.prod_settings
```

I hope, I helped you.

Comment: You don't have to have the `settings.py` inside an app folder.  You would need to modify the `wsgi.py` file and `manage.py` file to point to where ever the `settings.py` file is.  This works no matter if you are running in a development environment or production environment.